# ExecuteScalar() always returns NULL even though there is data in the database

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to make a simple memory game on visual Studio using C#. This game must keep some user records in the database. My database is not empty. This is part of my code :

```
string ConnectionString = @"Data Source =" + Application.StartupPath + @"\mydb.sdf";

SqlCeConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=" +Application.StartupPath + @"\mydb.sdf");
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand cmdt = new System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand(ConnectionString);
cmdt.CommandText = "insert into logs (Sessionid, score, Minutes, Hintcount, Errorcount, Level, Picname) values(@ID, @Score, @Minutes, @Hintcount, @Errorcount, 'Level 1', @Picname)";
cmdt.Connection = sqlConnection1;

sqlConnection1.Open();
{
    SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("select ID from Userrecords where ID=(select MAX(ID) from Userrecords) and Username='" + LoginInfo.UserID + "'", sqlConnection1);

    cmd.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.OutputParameters;


    int id = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

   cmdt.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Score", point);
   cmdt.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Minutes", time);
   cmdt.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hintcount", hbuttoncount);
   cmdt.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Errorcount", errorcount);
   cmdt.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Picname", nameused2);
   cmdt.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);

   cmdt.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.OutputParameters;
   cmdt.ExecuteNonQuery();
   sqlConnection1.Close();
}
```

I am trying to use executeScalar method, in order to retrieve the session ID from another table. But it always returns NULL, so it throws an exception. Is there any alternative that i can use?

Comment: temporarily use    "object val = cmd.ExecuteScalar();" just to see if its a different datatype.

Comment: temporarily change your sql to "select MAX(ID) from Userrecords" to see if it is because you have no rows matching the where clause.  or even temporaily change to "select 333 as fakevalue"

Comment: `(select MAX(ID) from Userrecords)` is not bound to the username btw, so unless `Username='" + LoginInfo.UserID + "'` actually has the `MAX(ID)` of *all* the rows, nothing will match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want the latest `ID` for this `Username`, then your query is wrong. Use:

```
var sql = @"SELECT MAX(ID) As Id 
            FROM Userrecords 
            WHERE Username = @UserName";
SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(sql, sqlConnection1);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = LoginInfo.UserID;
```

Your query returned the max-id if this record accidentially had the searched `Username`.